# Unable to get cuda to work in tensorflow

Tags: cuda, nvidia, tensorflow

I'm trying to use cuda to accelerate tensorflow. I'm running tensorflow using the docker image.

Firstly, when I launch the gpu image, it has a mismatch in the LT_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:

```
~# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
root@d578acbbc2cd:~# ls /usr/local/
bin  cuda  cuda-7.0  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src
```

There's no nvidia directory there. When I try to run the convolutional.py demo, it can't initialise the cuda support:

```
# python models/image/mnist/convolutional.py
Succesfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Succesfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Succesfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Succesfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 8
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.2.0-23-generic/modules.dep.bin'
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:466] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:98] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: d578acbbc2cd
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:106] hostname: d578acbbc2cd
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:131] libcuda reported version is: Not found: was unable to find libcuda.so DSO loaded into this program
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:242] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.68  Tue Dec  1 17:24:11 PST 2015
GCC version:  gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 
"""
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:135] kernel reported version is: 352.68
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:112] DMA: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 8
```

It then goes on to train using cpu only.

```
# find /usr -name libcuda.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
```

So in the docker image, there's only the gnu cpu cuda implementation. No NVIDIA stuff. In the host ubuntu 15.10 session, I have libcuda.so installed:

```
$ find /usr -name libcuda.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
/stubs/libcuda.so
```

So these seem to be stubs ... not sure why.

Is there some trick to getting this to work?

Comment: This looks like a broken linux kernel installation to me and nothing to do with CUDA. Also note that Ubuntu 15.10 is not currently supported by CUDA, so you are probably not going to get this to work, even after solving your botched kernel upgrade.

Comment: refer to [failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120389/6521116)

Answer (score 2):

Try rebuilding the Docker image directly from the Tensorflow repository (i.e. don't rely on the image on the container registry) and use https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker to run the container (the Docker command described in the Tensorflow documentation is not portable).

Comment: I got TensorFlow to run on 15.10 with CUDA acceleration, but not within the docker image. I guess I'll just have to wait for things to be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, though not in docker. The libcuda.so in /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs was a broken sym link. When I searched for libcuda.so it only turned up a file in a lib32 folder.

It seems that the problem was how I originally installed the NVIDIA device driver. At some point in the driver install process you're given the option to install the lib32 drivers. I had thought this meant in addition to lib64 drivers so I selected it. Turns out it only installs lib32 and not lib64 drivers.

I reinstalled the NIVDIA device driver, this time not selecting the lib32 'option'. Now tensorflow finds libcuda.so.

Comment: This sort of feedback seems better suited as a comment. It is not a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with running tensorflow on a Ubuntu machine after I upgraded my driver to 352.63 and 352.93. (I remember it works with 346.* but when I try to install 346., it installs 352. automatically for some reason).

I finally figured out that it's caused by permission issue. (I can run it with root) So, I changed the permission of the libcuda.so.352-63 file to executable by anyone and it works well now.

Hope this will be helpful to those still struggling with this issue.

I didn't try the docker one, but I guess it's also caused by permission setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

As mentioned here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/394
and 
http://kkjkok.blogspot.in/2016_08_01_archive.html

Answer (score 1):

After I updated NVIDIA driver to  378.09 on Ubuntu 14.10 I had the same error, 
although all the right for lib files were set correctly.
Thanks to @PhoenixQ, I tried to run with `sudo` and it worked.

After that I tried to run without `sudo` one more time and error disappeared. I'm not sure what ecxactly happened, but maybe something was configured during call with `sudo`, which was not possible withous `sudo`.

So the **solution:**

1. Try to run the same thing with `sudo`.
2. After this. Tryu running without `sudo`. Worked for me.